# Ruby: Extract elements from deeply nested JSON structure based on criteria

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

Want to extract every `marketID` from every market that has a `marketName == 'Moneyline'`. Tried a few combinations of `.map`s, `.reject`s, and/or `.select`s but can't narrow it down as the complicated structure is confusing me.

There are many `markets` in `events`, and there are many `events` as well. A sample of the structure (tried to edit it for brevity):

```
{"currencyCode"=>"GBP",
"eventTypes"=>[
    {"eventTypeId"=>6423,
    "eventNodes"=>[
        {"eventId"=>28017227,
        "event"=>
            {"eventName"=>"Philadelphia @ Seattle"
            },
            "marketNodes"=>[
                {"marketId"=>"1.128274650",
                "description"=>
                    {"marketName"=>"Moneyline"}
                },
                {"marketId"=>"1.128274625",
                "description"=>
                    {"marketName"=>"Winning Margin"}
                }}}]},
        {"eventId"=>28018251,
        "event"=>
            {"eventName"=>"Arkansas @ Mississippi State"
            },
            "marketNodes"=>[
                {"marketId"=>"1.128299882",
                "description"=>
                    {"marketName"=>"Under/Over 60.5pts"}
                },
                {"marketId"=>"1.128299881",
                "description"=>
                    {"marketName"=>"Moneyline"}
                }}}]},
        {"eventId"=> etc....
```

Tried all kinds of things, for example,

```
markets = json["eventTypes"].first["eventNodes"].map {|e| e["marketNodes"].map { |e| e["marketId"] } if (e["marketNodes"].map {|e| e["marketName"] == 'Moneyline'})}
markets.flatten
# => yields every marketId not every marketId with marketName of 'Moneyline'
```

Getting a simple array with every marketId from Moneyline markets with no other information is sufficient. Using Rails methods is fine too if preferred.

Sorry if my editing messed up the syntax. [Here's the source](https://www.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/allmarkets?eventTypeIds=6423&types=MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT&alt=json). It looks like this only with `=>` instead of `:` after parsing the JSON.

Thank you!

Comment: rather not use outside resources. this is in a rails app so either ruby or rails methods

Comment: Do you have an example with correct syntax?

Comment: @EricDuminil Sorry if my editing messed it up. See here: https://www.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/allmarkets?eventTypeIds=6423&types=MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT&alt=json In my console, it basically looks exactly like that only with `=>` instead of `:` after parsing. It's a little messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love nested maps and selects :D

```
require 'json'

hash = JSON.parse(File.read('data.json'))

moneyline_market_ids = hash["eventTypes"].map{|type|
  type["eventNodes"].map{|node|
    node["marketNodes"].select{|market|
      market["description"]["marketName"] == 'Moneyline'
    }.map{|market| market["marketId"]}
  }
}.flatten

puts moneyline_market_ids.join(', ')
#=> 1.128255531, 1.128272164, 1.128255516, 1.128272159, 1.128278718, 1.128272176, 1.128272174, 1.128272169, 1.128272148, 1.128272146, 1.128255464, 1.128255448, 1.128272157, 1.128272155, 1.128255499, 1.128272153, 1.128255484, 1.128272150, 1.128255748, 1.128272185, 1.128278720, 1.128272183, 1.128272178, 1.128255729, 1.128360712, 1.128255371, 1.128255433, 1.128255418, 1.128255403, 1.128255387
```

Comment: yowza. perfect. Thank you kindly! My head was hurting trying to figure it out.

Comment: Hey @eric-duminil, if you have a minute to spare, I have a more challenging brain teaser here. Source: https://www.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/allmarkets?eventTypeIds=7522&types=MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT,MARKET_RATES&alt=json. I want to select `marketIds == 'Moneyline'` but only those with `countryCode == 'US' || 'GB'` OR `eventName.include?(' @ ')`. (`space` before and after the `@`). I tried different combos of `map` and `select` but some nodes don't have 'countryCode` which complicates things. There is some overlap with those last two criteria, so `uniq` may be necessry? TIA!

Comment: Please write another question.

Comment: Right! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708340/ruby-extract-from-deeply-nested-json-structure-based-on-multiple-criteria. Really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's another possible answer, this time with regexen. It is shorter but might break depending on your input data. It reads the json data directly as String :

```
json = File.read('data.json')

market_ids   = json.scan(/(?<="marketId":")[\d\.]+/)
market_names = json.scan(/(?<="marketName":")[^"]+/)

moneyline_market_ids = market_ids.zip(market_names).select{|id,name| name=="Moneyline"}.map{|id,_| id}
puts moneyline_market_ids.join(', ')
#=> 1.128255531, 1.128272164, 1.128255516, 1.128272159, 1.128278718, 1.128272176, 1.128272174, 1.128272169, 1.128272148, 1.128272146, 1.128255464, 1.128255448, 1.128272157, 1.128272155, 1.128255499, 1.128272153, 1.128255484, 1.128272150, 1.128255748, 1.128272185, 1.128278720, 1.128272183, 1.128272178, 1.128255729, 1.128360712, 1.128255371, 1.128255433, 1.128255418, 1.128255403, 1.128255387
```

It outputs the same result as the other answer.