# Ruby: Extract from deeply nested JSON structure based on multiple criteria

Tags: json, ruby, hash

I want to select any `marketId` of `marketName == 'Moneyline'` but only those with `countryCode == 'US' || 'GB'` OR `eventName.include?(' @ ')`. (`space` before and after the `@`). I tried different combos of map and select but some nodes don't have `countryCode` which complicates things for me. [This](https://www.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1/allmarkets?eventTypeIds=7522&types=MARKET_DESCRIPTION,EVENT,MARKET_RATES&alt=json) is the source, but a sample of what it might look like:

```
{"currencyCode"=>"GBP",
"eventTypes"=>[
    {"eventTypeId"=>7522,
    "eventNodes"=>[
        {"eventId"=>28024331,
        "event"=>
            {"eventName"=>"EWE Baskets Oldenburg v PAOK Thessaloniki BC"
            },
            "marketNodes"=>[
                {"marketId"=>"1.128376755",
                "description"=>
                    {"marketName"=>"Moneyline"}
                },
                {"marketId"=>"1.128377853",
                "description"=>
                    {"marketName"=>"Start Lublin +7.5"}
                }}}]},
        {"eventId"=>28023434,
        "event"=>
            {"eventName"=>"Asseco Gdynia v Start Lublin",
            "countryCode"=>"PL",
            },
            "marketNodes"=>
                [{"marketId"=>"1.128377853", ETC...
```

Comment: Try using recursion? I'll write up a full answer later...

Comment: You can also use json path

Comment: When you give an example please do the following. 1. Make it a valid Ruby object (no "ETC...")  so readers can run their code against your example. 2. Show the desired return value. 3. Simplify the example by stripping out extraneous elements. Since it's obvious that `hash = JSON.parse(File.read('data.json'))`, here you may want to just present the hash rather than the JSON string and make no reference to JSON. 4. Assign a variable to each input object (e.g, `h = {currency...}`). This allows readers to refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698572/ruby-extract-elements-from-deeply-nested-json-structure-based-on-criteria/40698808?noredirect=1#comment68644516_40698808), you just need to add a select on eventNodes :

```
require 'json'

json = File.read('data.json')
hash = JSON.parse(json)

moneyline_market_ids = hash["eventTypes"].map{|type|
  type["eventNodes"].select{|event_node|
    ['US', 'GB'].include?(event_node["event"]["countryCode"]) || event_node["event"]["eventName"].include?(' @ ')
  }.map{|event|
    event["marketNodes"].select{|market|
      market["description"]["marketName"] == 'Moneyline'
    }.map{|market|
      market["marketId"]
    }
  }
}.flatten

puts moneyline_market_ids.join(', ')
#=> 1.128255531, 1.128272164, 1.128255516, 1.128272159, 1.128278718, 1.128272176, 1.128272174, 1.128272169, 1.128272148, 1.128272146, 1.128255464, 1.128255448, 1.128272157, 1.128272155, 1.128255499, 1.128272153, 1.128255484, 1.128272150, 1.128255748, 1.128272185, 1.128278720, 1.128272183, 1.128272178, 1.128255729, 1.128360712, 1.128255371, 1.128255433, 1.128255418, 1.128255403, 1.128255387
```

If you want to keep the country code and name information with the id:

```
moneyline_market_ids = hash["eventTypes"].map{|type|
  type["eventNodes"].map{|event_node|
    [event_node, event_node["event"]["countryCode"], event_node["event"]["eventName"]]
  }.select{|_, country, event_name|
    ['US', 'GB'].include?(country) || event_name.include?(' @ ')
  }.map{|event, country, event_name|
    event["marketNodes"].select{|market|
      market["description"]["marketName"] == 'Moneyline'
    }.map{|market|
      [market["marketId"],country,event_name]
    }
  }
}.flatten(2)

require 'pp'
pp moneyline_market_ids
#=> [["1.128255531", "US", "Philadelphia @ Seattle"],
#   ["1.128272164", "US", "Arkansas @ Mississippi State"],
#   ["1.128255516", "US", "New England @ San Francisco"],
#   ["1.128272159", "US", "Indiana @ Michigan"],
#   ["1.128278718", "CA", "Edmonton @ Ottawa"],
#   ["1.128272176", "US", "Arizona State @ Washington"],
#   ["1.128272174", "US", "Alabama A&M @ Auburn"],
#    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so darn close to this on my own but kept getting a syntax error. Appreciate it.

Comment: Wow, that 2nd one could be really handy... thank you for going the extra mile!